# Master-Detail App Autorotation for DetailViewController not aligned if user rotates while viewing MasterViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, master-detail

I have a simple Master-Detail application with a MasterViewController and a DetailViewController.  Inside of the DetailViewController I have implemented the following code so that when the view is rotated my two buttons are positioned properly.

```
  - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:
(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
                                         duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {   firstButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 240, 50, 50);
        secondButton.frame = CGRectMake(390, 240, 50, 50);
    }
    else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        firstButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 240, 50, 50);
        secondButton.frame = CGRectMake(390, 240, 50, 50);
    }
    else
    {
        firstButton.frame = CGRectMake(80, 390, 50, 50);
        secondButton.frame = CGRectMake(190, 390, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

If the iPhone isn't rotated until the DetailViewController is in view, then the buttons are positioned properly. But if the user rotates the iPhone while viewing the MasterViewController table view and then taps an item, when the DetailViewController opens, the buttons are not positioned correctly.

So how can I or where do I position the buttons from the MasterViewController?  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check `interfaceOrientation` property of `UIViewController` in your viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear for example:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = self.interfaceOrientation;
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {   firstButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 240, 50, 50);
        secondButton.frame = CGRectMake(390, 240, 50, 50);
    }
    else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        firstButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 240, 50, 50);
        secondButton.frame = CGRectMake(390, 240, 50, 50);
    }
    else
    {
        firstButton.frame = CGRectMake(80, 390, 50, 50);
        secondButton.frame = CGRectMake(190, 390, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tremendous help. I was afraid my title was so confusing I wouldn't get a response.  The only problem is I get the following warning: "Implicit conversion from enumeration type UIDeviceOrientation to different enumeration type UIInterfaceOrientation"

Comment: After I searched a little more, I edited my answer, that should be good

Comment: That did it and it works perfectly.  I placed the code in the viewWillAppear.  Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. By the way you can use the macro UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation) for checking both UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft and UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight.

Comment: New problem with this same app. One of the buttons plays a short video on the UIImageView. I have it setup to play the video centered when iPhone is in portrait mode and full screen when in landscape. Video plays fine and will transition from portrait to landscape but if rotated while playing and closes, the underlying image and buttons are not properly aligned. They are positioned as they were before I implemented the code into the ViewWillAppear.  Any ideas as to what I can do to make sure the underlying assets are aligned properly when the rotation occurs while the video is playing?